# When whores talk about honor

Tags: offensive-language, proverbs

There is a proverb or saying in Arabic and the exact translation is...

> "When whores talk about honor"

...this is said when someone points out other people's mistakes while he/she makes the same mistakes or something even worse.

is there anything similar or equivalent in English?

Comment: "Honor among thieves" ... https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44388/is-there-honour-among-thieves-or-not

Comment: While it is legitimate to discuss the meaning of this phrase, I feel I ought to add that prostitution is not in itself dishonourable.  It is a profession for which there is a market.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Those who live in glass houses should not throw stones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Those_who_live_in_glass_houses_should_not_throw_stones).

[The pot calling the kettle black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_pot_calling_the_kettle_black).

[Take the plank out of your own eye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_7:5).